# How to fix this window on a stud wall?

Tags: wood, windows, installation, studs

We recently bought two of these windows on a garage sale of a local window provider.  We were so happy to have found two windows of the same size with the right color on sale that we quickly bought them.

Now that our shed is advancing, we are wondering how to fix this window on a stud wall.  It wouldn't be a problem if there was a wood frame or a nail fin.  Sadly, there's nothing like that on it.  We are having a really hard time figuring it out.

Here's some picture of the window.

[image: Window Outside 3D]
[image: Window Inside 3D]
[image: Window Close View]

We are currently thinking of replacing the larger Styrofoam by a custom made wood plank, so we can create our own wood frame.  Although, I don't think we should have to do that... maybe there's something we are not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we removed the styrofoam and inserted some wood planks. We blended the metal on the ends to hold the wood and then screw everything together.  Luckily, we had all the needed tools.  (Thickness planner being the most useful to get the right thickness.)

After that, it's just like installing a typical window.

Answer (score 2):

These may be "insert" window replacements/upgrades.  An existing window has the jambs and parting bead removed.  Then this unit is inserted and the original stop bead on the outside and inside holds this unit in place.

You can use the same idea.. trim the rough opening out so this window fits snugly.  (Trim it like you would a door, with jambs and trim inside and, as needed, outside).  Add stop bead on both sides of the window to cover the gap and hold it in place.

Comment: I think you are right about the "insert" window replacement.  Thanks for your suggestion.  Although, this window is way ticker than my stud and aspenite wall; it would have stand outside too much if we would have used the "insert" mechanism.